# How to Enumerate _DRIVER_OBJECT windows?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

Is there a way to enumerate all the _DRIVER_OBJECT present in windows? 
volatility does that(using driverscan option) but it uses physical dump and they scan for tag memory. Is there any other way to do that? I am looking for solution where i can write a kernel driver to get this information.

Using _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, I am able to get size, base and name of all the entry. But IRP handler information is in _DRIVER_OBJECT and I dont know how to reach there from _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.

_DRIVER_OBJECT  does point to _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY but there is no way back to _DRIVER_OBJECT.